# ORA-00913: too many values insert wm_concat string into table

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, ora-00913

When I use wm_concat to concatenate several tuples into one tuple.

For example

ID     Items
1      'apple'
2      'peach'
2      'banana'

```
 declare 
  v_name_l: varchar(100);
  v_name_b: varchar(100);
begin
     select wm_concat(Items) into v_name_l from Item group by ID having count(*)=1;
     select wm_concat(Items) into v_name_b from Item group by ID having count(*)=2;
     execute immediate ('Insert into  apr values('||v_name_l||','||v_name_b||')');
end;
```

Another table apr structure  is
Name1     Name2

name1 and nam2  are varchar(100);

There is a error raise  in

```
*execute immediate execute immediate ('Insert into  apr values('||v_name_l||','||v_name_b||')')"

   ORA-00913: too many values
```

I think the wm_concat to concatenate mutiple rows in one single string;
How can I fix it?

Comment: :please post the code and the table structure.

Answer (score 0):

I think nothing wrong with wm_concat queries. You just need to escape quotes. Because you are referencing your query as string in this case lets say:

**v_name_l** is *`'apple, peach, banana'`* and **v_name_b** is '`x, y, z`'

So when you define as current query:

```
Insert into  apr values('||v_name_l||','||v_name_b||')
```

Oracle translates to:

***Insert into  apr values(apple, peach, banana, x, y, z)***

And database recognize every comma separated value as a column but the table has just two column instead of 6. If you escape quotes:

```
Insert into  apr values('''||v_name_l||''','''||v_name_b||''');
```

then oracle will read like:

***Insert into  apr values('apple, peach, banana', 'x, y, z');***

I hope that was the reason:)